# How to run an swift app when Terminate?

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, background

I want to store some information in the local database sqlite, if internet is disconnected or even when the app is Terminate. What is your suggestion for the job? How to handle identify these events?

***when app is terminated not when app is going to terminated

Comment: you can't do that. Apple doesn't allows you.

Answer (score 0):

> **Apple does not allow any operation when app is terminated**

You can perform your operation, exact before your app will terminate.

`UIApplicationDelegate` has a delegate method - `applicationWillTerminate`, is called when your app is about to terminate.

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate.
}
```

You can set you code to store information/data, in block of this method

For Internet Connectivity for iOS 8+, you can check internet connectivity status, during a web service API calls. Web service API response will have this error, if there is no internet connectivity. You can perform operation when error code = **-1005**

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo=0x7ba8e5b0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a6957e0 "The network connection was lost."}
```

Comment: Read the question again, OP is saying **when app is terminated** not when app is going to terminated.

Answer (score 0):

When any application terminate before termination it goes to background mode for very few time and following methods will get execute in App Delegate class:-

[optional func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622997-applicationdidenterbackground)

You can write your script to save data in local database. 
Also you can use [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)
 to get notify if network status is changing.